# How to check if a variable is nil

Tags: swift

I have a variable

```
var a: [AnyObject? -> Void]
```

and I am adding data in to it by append method. Now I want to check if the variable is nil or not. I tried using `[]` but not working and also tried `""`, this also not working, can anyone tell what is the meaning of this variable and how to check if it is nil.

Comment: Maybe, you just want to check if the array is empty?

Comment: yes i want to check if it is empty.

Answer (score 16):

As far as I understand, var `a` is an Array of functions that take an optional Object of any type, and return void. So these functions's parameter IS optional, but the Array itself isn't : it cannot be nil, or it would be declared `[AnyObject? -> Void]?` , no?

**EDIT** : if, nevertheless, you declared this `a` as an optional (but WHY would you do that ?) - adding a `?` - you check an optional existence with `if let` :

```
if let b = a {
// a not nil, do some stuff
} else {
// a is null
}
```

If you just want to check if the array is empty, use `isEmpty` method from Swift Array

Comment: if i wanted to check if it is nil, what should i do?

Comment: As @Vinzzz already wrote, defined in that way *it cannot be `nil`*

Answer (score 7):

Update: **Xcode 7.3 Swift 2.2**

If you want to check if a variable is nil you should use if let to unwrap if for you. There is no need to create a second var.

```
let str = "123"
var a = Int(str)        
if let a = a {
    print(a)
}
```

Or

```
if let a = Int(str) {
    print(a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, nil is not a pointer—it is the absence of a value of a certain type. Optionals of any type can be set to nil, not just object types.

So, You can check it with below code:

```
let possibleNumber = "123"
let convertedNumber = possibleNumber.toInt()

if convertedNumber != nil {
    println("convertedNumber contains some integer value.")
}
// prints "convertedNumber contains some integer value."
```

Please refer this about **[nil](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)** for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3.0

```
if let imageURL = dictObj["list_image"] as? String {
   print(imageURL)
}
```

Comment: You can improve the quality of this Answer by explaining how it works and thus how it improves the Questioner's situation.  Also, you have not addressed part of the Question, namely where they ask "can anyone tell what is the meaning of this variable".

Comment: Please don't duplicate your answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43363148/2415822, http://stackoverflow.com/a/43363066/2415822

Answer (score 1):

You can use if let. if let is a special structure in Swift that allows you to check if an Optional holds a value, and in case it does – do something with the unwrapped value.

```
var a:Int=0
if let b=a{
   println(a)
} else {
   println("Value - nil")
}
```

But for Strings you can also use `.isEmpty()` If you have initialized it to `""`.

```
var str:String=""
if !str.isEmpty(){
   println(str)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the above solutions worked when I was using an AVFoundation object.

I would get `Type 'AVCaptureDeviceInput does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'` when I tried `if (audioDeviceInput)` and I would get `Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AVCaptureDeviceInput' and 'nil'`.

**Solution in my situation**

```
if (audioDeviceInput.isEqual(nil))
```

`nil` is a pointer like any other and can be referenced as such, which is why this works.