# How do we test for nils in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, null, xcode7

How do we properly test for nils?

Xcode 7.01 is throwing a new error we didn't have before.

We are receiving this error:

> "Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   '[NSObject: Anyobject]' and 'NilLiteralConvertible'"

..from this code:

```
// send request data to phone and handle reply or error
var didOpenParent : Bool = WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(requestData, reply: { (reply, error) -> Void in

            // if we get a response, handle it appropriately
            if error == nil && reply != nil 
            {
                // code continues
```

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) gives examples of testing for nils using "!=" as we are doing. Trying some the answers suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317325/how-to-check-a-variable-is-nil-in-swift) such as checking if reply.isEqual(nil) or reply.isEmpty did not work for us.

What are we missing?

Answer (score 2):

`reply` here is of type `[NSObject : AnyObject]`, which is a **non-optional** [dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113) type. You don't need to — and, as you've discovered, can't — check if it's nil.

Comment: So is it accurate to say based on your answer that we can just completely delete that if statement and the code is fine?

Comment: Yes, you *cannot* check something for nil which is non-optional (or more specifically, something which isn't NilLiteralConvertible and Equatable)

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the non-optional dictionary for nil but you can make sure if the app sent u a reply dictionary by calling isEmpty

```
if error == nil && !reply.isEmpty
```